# issue with simple action - retrieve a string field based on ID field of the row not working (flutter + firebase)

Tags: flutter, firebase, function

i am working on a school project using flutter and i have to retrieve the name of a product based on an ID

the function is below

```
String retrieveItemName(String itemID) {
  
  // go through a firebase collection menuItems and retrieve the name field based on the ID argument
  String itemName = '';
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('menuItems')
      .doc(itemID)
      .get()
      .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
    if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
     ** itemName = documentSnapshot.data()!['name'];**
    }
  });
  return itemName;
```

seems simple enough
i have a collection in firebase called menuItems
This collection has an ID (auto generated from firebase) and a name.
I retrieve the ID from somewhere else and try to map it to the name.

the issue i get is
**The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try defining the operator '[**]'
this refer to the line :

```
** itemName = documentSnapshot.data()!['name'];**
```

any suggestion on how to handle this issue?

i am at loss, i tried modifying my function but im not sure how to

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to type cast your Object to Map<String, dynamic>.

Solution 1:

```
itemName = (documentSnapshot.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>)['name'];
```

Solution 2:

```
final Map <String, dynamic> item = documentSnapshot.data()!;
itemName = item['itemName'];
```

I hope this solutions help you solve your problem.

Comment: I'm so glad I could help! Can you mark this as the accepted answer please?